# is it allowed to use non renewal in app subscription for iOS application which contains Magazine subscription iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing, non-renewing-subscription

I'm working on a iOS Mobile application which contains News and Magazine contents. 
In my app, the subscribed users can access the paid contents by simply Login to their online account.

My application has to manage subscription across different platforms(mobile and web).I think auto renewal is not a good option for me. Can I use non-renewal in-app purchase for my iOS application?

Answer (score 0):

My App is successfully uploaded on Appstore in News category. You can use Non-renewal in-app purchase for server maintaining subscription based apps. If your app contains news and magazine and if you think non-renewal subscription is appropriate, then while uploading your app select news category instead of news and magazine category.
In News and Magazine category we can only use auto-renewal subscriptions.
Other categories can use non-renewal subscriptions.